# Spyder does a new plot for every plot command - how to reset to default?

Tags: python, plot, spyder

The way spyder used to work in my environment is the following:

```
plt.plot(x)
plt.plot(y)
```

it will by default use the same plot to draw the lines x,y.

But currently it does one plot per command. Does anyone know how to reset to default?

I am aware that there were similar questions here on stack in the past. But none could really solve my issue. Adding the magic command `%matplotlib inline` also does not solve the issue and is more troublesome too. Thanks for your help!